# Algorithm to get periods from JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js

I'm working on an algorithm to find periods in JSON array of object. The JSON array is as follows :

```
[
 {
   "year": 1960,
   "month": 1,
   "colval": 1
 },
 {
   "year": 1960,
   "month": 2,
   "colval": 1
 },
 {
   "year": 1960,
   "month": 3,
   "colval": 0
 },
 ....
 ....
 {
   "year": 2016,
   "month": 12,
   "colval": 0
 }]
```

This array is consists of the object that contains "year", "month" and "colval". (colval can be only 0, 1, 2 and 3)

Array starts from 1960-1 to 2016-12 and I want to get periods that colval > 0 and there can be only 1 zero value in this period. If zero value repeats twice than it is not counted as period. And period must last at least 6 months.

For example : (Only showing the values of colval) 
Bold values are the selected periods.

1-2-1-3-0-0-0-**1-1-1-2-2-3-2-1-3-3-2**-0-0-0-**1-2-2-2-0-3-3-3-3**-0-0-0-1-0-1-0-**2-0-2-2-3-3-3**

I tried with pure JS to count values if it is greater than 0 and make it zero when I access to two "zeros", but I still don't get the periods with start and end.

Here is the code I'm working on :

```
        var counter = 0;
        var zeroCounter = 0;
        var startArray = null;          
        var periods = [];

        $.each(groupArr, function (i, v) {
            if (v.colval > 0) {
                if (counter == 0) {
                    startArray = v;
                }

                counter++;
            }
            else {
                if (zeroCounter > 1) {
                    if (counter > 5) {
                        endArray = v;
                        periods.push({ start: startArray, end: v });
                        startArray = null;
                        counter = 0;
                    }                       
                }
                else {
                    zeroCounter++;
                }
            }
        });
```

**Update 1 :** The sequence also cannot start or end with "zeros".

**Update 2 :** There is also one more requirement added today that if there is 12 months between occurence of zeros, then this zero will also added to period and continues with other numbers. For example :

0-0-**1-1-0-1-2-2-1-3-1-2-2-3-2-2-3-0-2-1-1-3-2**-0-0

**Update 3 :** Due to "reduce" function support in IE, method should be implemented in Underscore to bypass browser support issues.

**Update 4 :** New Examples :

-> 1-2-1-3-0-0-0-**1-1-1-2-2-3-2-1-3-3-2**-0-0-0-**1-2-2-2-0-3-3-3-3**-0-0-0-1-0-1-0-2-0-2-2-3-3-3

-> 0-0-**1-1-0-1-2-2-1-3-1-2-2-3-2-2-3-0-2-1-1-3-2**-0-0

-> 1-1-3-0-1-0-0-**1-0-1-2-3-2-2-2-3-1**-0-1-2-3-0-1-2-0-0-0-1-2-3-3

- Bold values are accepted ones.

Comment: Wouldn't the first run be `1-1-1-2-2-3-2-1-3-3-2-0`? It satisfies the conditions you've stated.

Comment: Is there an additional requirement that a sequence cannot start with a zero?

Comment: Yes, you are right, one more requirement, the sequence cannot start or end with "zeros".

Comment: which one of the connected (with zero) do you want, the loger sequence, the first, the last the one with greater values? what happens with multiple options, do you want then the solution with more parts, instead of possible longer single part? please add some more use cases for my question.

Comment: We are trying to catch the longer periods with least blanks (zeros). Examples are as :

-> 1-2-1-3-0-0-0-<b>1-1-1-2-2-3-2-1-3-3-2</b>-0-0-0-<b>1-2-2-2-0-3-3-3-3</b>-0-0-0-1-0-1-0-2-0-2-2-3-3-3

-> 0-0-<b>1-1-0-1-2-2-1-3-1-2-2-3-2-2-3-0-2-1-1-3-2</b>-0-0

-> 1-1-3-0-1-0-0-<b>1-0-1-2-3-2-2-2-3-1</b>-0-1-2-3-0-1-2-0-0-0-1-2-3-3

* Bold values are accepted ones. Hope these are explained my case.

Comment: please add this information to the question. what is with the last part of the first division and what is with the part in the second division should it be separated, because it containse two zeroes  and what is with the last division, what is with a longer part of `1-2-3-2-2-2-3-1-0-1-2-3`?

Comment: Especially, we are trying to catch longest period and "zeros" with one month and months between two "zeros" are important rather than count of zeros. If you catch a long period with 4 zeros with difference of at least 12 months each, then it is no problem.

Comment: why not in the last example `1-2-3-0-1-2`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
var arr = [{"year": 1960,"month": 1,"colval": 1},{"year": 1960,"month": 10,"colval": 1},{"year": 1960,"month": 3,"colval": 0},{"year": 2016,"month": 12,"colval": 0 }];

var periods = arr.reduce((a, c, index, array) => {
  if(c.colval == 0 && index < (array.length - 1) && array[index + 1].colval == 0 && a[a.length - 1].length || (c.colval == 0 && a[a.length - 1].some(v => c.colval == 0))){
    a.push([]);
  }else{
    a[a.length - 1].push(c);
  }
  return a;
}, [[]]).reduce((a, c) => {
  if(c.length >= 2){
    c.sort((v1, v2) => ((v1.year + v1.month) - (v2.year + v2.month)));
    var minMonths = (c[0].year * 12) + c[0].month;
    var maxMonths = (c[c.length - 1].year * 12)  + c[c.length - 1].month;
    if(maxMonths - minMonths >= 6){
        a.push(c);
    }
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(periods)
```

The first `reduce` creates a new period when two consecutive objects with `colval` equal to `0` occur or the current object has `colval` equal to `0` and there is already such an object in the current period.

The second reduce keeps only the periods that are bigger or equal to 6 months.

You may probably want to simplify the `if` statement in the first `reduce`, I've probably made that more complicated then it has to be.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This is almost working except including "zeros" at the beginning. I've also updated the post with two new requirements. I'll try to update your code and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
let values = [
   { "year": 1960, "month": 1,  "colval": 1 },
   { "year": 1960, "month": 2,  "colval": 1 },
   { "year": 1960, "month": 3,  "colval": 2 },
   { "year": 1960, "month": 4,  "colval": 0 },
   { "year": 1960, "month": 5,  "colval": 2 },
   { "year": 1960, "month": 6,  "colval": 3 },
   { "year": 1960, "month": 7,  "colval": 0 },
   { "year": 1960, "month": 8,  "colval": 0 },
   { "year": 1960, "month": 9,  "colval": 2 },
   { "year": 1960, "month": 10, "colval": 3 },
   { "year": 1960, "month": 11, "colval": 1 },
   { "year": 1960, "month": 12, "colval": 2 },
   { "year": 1961, "month": 1,  "colval": 1 },
   { "year": 1961, "month": 2,  "colval": 3 },
   { "year": 1961, "month": 3,  "colval": 0 },
   { "year": 1961, "month": 4,  "colval": 1 },
   { "year": 1961, "month": 5,  "colval": 0 }
 ]

function getPeriods(months) {
  let periods = []; // this is an array of periods
  let prevInPeriod = false;
  let currPeriod;
  let zeros = 0;

  months.forEach(function (month) {
    let currIsZero = (month.colval === 0);
    let currInPeriod = !currIsZero || !zeros;
    if (!prevInPeriod && currIsZero) {
      currInPeriod = false;
    }

    if (!month.colval) {
      zeros++;
    }

    if (!prevInPeriod && !currInPeriod) {
      return;
    }

    if (!prevInPeriod && currInPeriod) { // entering period
      currPeriod = [month]; // creating new period with date
    } else if (prevInPeriod && currInPeriod) { // still in period
      currPeriod.push(month); // pushing new values
    } else if (prevInPeriod && !currInPeriod) { // period ends
      periods.push(currPeriod); // saving current period into results
      zeros = 0;
    }

    prevInPeriod = currInPeriod;
  });

  // checking the last period if it's in a results
  if (periods[periods.length - 1] !== currPeriod) {
    periods.push(currPeriod);
  }

  // filtering out periods which are shorter than 6
  periods = periods.filter(period => period.length >= 6);

  return periods;
}
```

Here you have jsfiddle with tests: https://jsfiddle.net/7awg75rh/1/

1. In above code, I iterate through all months in your array
2. Compare previous month with current one
3. Each iteration could have four states: *not in period*, *in period*, *leaving period*, *entering period*
4. In each scenario, I do a different action. Either, do nothing, adding month to current period, creating new period with current month or saving period
5. At the end, I filter out periods shorter than 6.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but this excludes "zero" in periods which concludes wrong periods.